# Can NCAA Football Dynasties Be Played Between Consoles?

Tags: ncaa-football-11

In NCAA Football 11, it is possible to play in dynasty mode across different console systems? I have a friend with the game and a PS3 and I have an Xbox360.

Is it possible for us to play in a dynasty league together?

Comment: Sure, you just have to buy your friend a new Xbox 360

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No because the PS3 and Xbox Live networks are not compatible nor connected to each other. There are very few games that allow multiplayer across different platforms. Due to the similar architecture between the Xbox and Windows (PC), you are more likely to see cross-platform multiplayer there, but it is still incredibly rare.